# How can I integrate complexity verification while using a PasswordBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, passwordbox

I have an application that needs to have the user create a passphrase.  As such, there are various rules that need to be tested against the passphrase as it's being entered.

These rules are pretty typical-- the value must be a certain length, have one upper, one lower, include some special characters, etc.

However, since this is a WPF application using a `PasswordBox` control, and the resulting value is very sensitive, how can I setup a complexity comparison system that dynamically checks the passphrase as the user is typing?

To be clear, I have a list of all requirements in a text label below the passphrase creation PasswordBox element.  As the user types, a validator shows which requirements are met and which ones are still needed. I also have an entropy calculator which give a typical "OK, Good, Strong, Very Strong" indicator once requirements are met.  This is why I need to find a way to securely validate the value as the user is typing.

How can I accomplish this without emitting insecure .Net strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to `PasswordChanged` but don't use `Password` property if you care about securely storing your sensetive value. Instead, do this:

```
private void OnPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {            
    using (var pwd = ((PasswordBox) sender).SecurePassword) {
        int length = pwd.Length;
        if (length == 0) {
            // string empty, do something
            return;
        }
        bool hasSpecial = false;
        bool hasUpper = false;
        bool hasLower = false;
        bool hasDigit = false;
        // etc
        // allocate unmanaged memory and copy string there
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(pwd);
        try {
            // each char in that string is 2 bytes, not one (it's UTF-16 string)
            for (int i = 0; i < length * 2; i += 2) {
                // so use ReadInt16 and convert resulting "short" to char
                var ch = Convert.ToChar(Marshal.ReadInt16(ptr + i));
                // run your checks
                hasSpecial |= IsSpecialChar(ch);
                hasUpper |= Char.IsUpper(ch);
                hasLower |= Char.IsLower(ch);
                hasDigit |= Char.IsDigit(ch);                        
            }

        }
        finally {
            // don't forget to zero memory to remove password from it                    
            Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

That way you never build .NET string during your validation, and every trace of password is cleared from memory when you finish.